# T-SQL Case Then Else Command inside Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, case

I have to preface this by telling you that I am just learning SQL. My task is to validate a report generated by T-SQL written by a consultant that used to work for our company. Can someone explain to me what the following section is doing? I understand the idea of a LEFT OUTER JOIN, but I don't understand how the case statement evaluates.

```
From
ShipmentQty
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ShipmentCost ON
          Case when ShipmentQty.RSLDNM <> 0 Then
0
          Else
            ShipmentQty.SDSHPN
          End = ShipmentCost.FHSHPN
      AND    
          ShipmentQty.RSLDNM = ShipmentCost.FHLDNM
```

I assume that the expression runs without error, but again, my task is not to run the SQL, only to validate each step of the code. Thank you in advance and please forgive my inexperience.

Answer (score 0):

It just means that if ShipmentQty.RSLDNM is not 0, then use 0, otherwise, use ShipmentQty.SDSHPN

Answer (score 0):

It can be easier to understand the logic without the `case`.  This is probably the equivalent logic:

```
From ShipmentQty LEFT OUTER JOIN
     ShipmentCost
     ON ((ShipmentCost.FHSHPN = 0 AND ShipmentQty.RSLDNM <> 0) OR
         (ShipmentCost.FHSHPN = ShipmentQty.SDSHPN AND ShipmentQty.RSLDNM = 0)
        ) AND
        ShipmentQty.RSLDNM = ShipmentCost.FHLDNM
```

I say "probably" because this does not take `NULL` values of `ShipmentQty.RSLDNM` into account.  So, if `RSLDNM` is zero, then the comparison is `FHSHPN` to `SDSHPN`.  If `RSLDNM` is not zero, then `FHSHPN` needs to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

the join is simple, the case is just a condition ([Watch this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)), when the field ShipmentQty.RSLDNM <> 0 then the join will use a 0 as value, if else the join will use ShipmentQty.SDSHPN as value.